# How to pass parameters with link_to tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, parameters

I am new to ruby on rails.
 
I am using ***match ":controller(/:action(/:id))", :via => [:GET, :PUT]*** as routing system.  
I am using *acts_as_votable* gem to setup voting system for posts.
Currently I am in **posts#show** page. I have two links one is **upvote** and the other is **downvote**.
After I click **upvote**, I want to  hit the **posts#upvote** action and then redirect to **posts#show**(same page) page again.
For that i need to pass the parameter of **:id**(post) in upvote action. 
If I use

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

in posts#vote , It throws an error, because we are not passing the **:id** to params hash. 
How to pass the **:id**(post) to params hash when I click the **upvote** button inorder to get ridoff the error I am getting.

here is the **posts#upvote** action code.

```
def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.upvote_from User.find(session[:user_id])
    redirect_to(:controller => "posts", :action => "show", :id => @post.id)    
end
```

Here is the link tag in **posts#show** page.

```
<%= link_to({:controller => "posts", :action => "upvote"}) do %>                        
    <span>Like</span>
    <span>(<%= @post.get_upvotes.size %>)</span>                        
<% end %>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: `localhost:3000/posts/1` where `1` is your `:id`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the view code where you call `link_to`.

Comment: What happens if you hit `/posts/vote/1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already doing it correctly in the controller, you just need to include the :id in the link_to url options:

```
<%= link_to(:controller => "posts", :action => "up vote", :id => @post) do %>
    <span>Like</span>
    <span>(<%= @post.get_upvotes.size %>)</span>
<% end %>
```

Note: you don't need to call `id` on the post, rails will automatically figure this out for you.

A better solution, would be to use resource routes for you Post object. then add upvote/downvote actions:

```
# in config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
    member do
        match "upvote", :as => :upvote, :via => [:get, :put]
    end
end
```

Rails will automatically create url helpers that you can use in your views

```
# in show html.erb
<%= link_to(upvote_post_url(@post)) do %>
    <span>Like</span>
    <span>(<%= @post.get_upvotes.size %>)</span>
<% end %>
```

the advantage to this is simpler code, and the ability change your routes with having to update template code.

Rails has already done all the heavy lifting of how to make and link to urls, to be faster at plumbing rails views and controllers together, you should definitely read the official guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, then may look daunting at first, but they will quickly become second knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

EDITED:

```
<%= link_to "Upvote", "#{Rails.root}/posts/upvote/#{@post.id}" %>
```

Passing in the @post.id will pass in that object's id in the params hash (as params[:id]).

Comment: I am using match ":controller(/:action(/:id))", :via => [:GET, :PUT] as routing system. After rake routes, it is only showing two routes.  Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
  root GET      /                                      users#login
       GET|POST /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format) :controller#:action

Comment: Well, I'm not sure the exact syntax for referencing routes like that from, say, a link_to call, but maybe try something like this: <%= link_to "upvote", "posts/upvote/#{@post.id}" %>. Let me know if that works, and I'll edit my answer to include it.

Comment: I posts#upvote, I should actually use the @post variable for "@post.upvote_from User.find(session[:user_id])" method. I need to grab the post after clicking the upvote button

Comment: What I'm saying is if you use link_to to provide a link with the posts/upvote/1 format (by passing in `@post.id` as the last part of the url), then from the upvote action, you can find that post again by saying `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: I passed the url as you said, but i am getting the error   No route matches [GET] "/posts/show/posts/upvote/6". But 6 is the actual post id

Comment: Just edited my link_to code sample in the answer. Try that out instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97898/discussion-between-akash-pinnaka-and-michael-cruz).

Comment: You should NEVER need to write `Rails.root` in the view, this will use the file system directory of your website on the server, which is completely useless to the user.

Comment: ahh fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try by hitting following localhost URL from your machine:

```
localhost:3000/posts/upvote/1 # where 1 is your :id
```

I would recommend you to go through [Ruby on Rais Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Comment: As i already mentioned I am using match ":controller(/:action(/:id))", :via => [:GET, :PUT] as routing system and The link should hit the posts#upvote action. Please help me on these issue